# Customized codename one android permission strings

Tags: codenameone

Is there a list of localization property names for codenameone "hardcoded" strings?

I found ***pull.down*** and ***pull.release*** properties to change `pull to refresh strings`, but don't know how to change strings in ***android permission dialog** ("Requires permission", "Don't Ask", "Ask again")

[see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LubVB.png)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I dived into codenameone android implementation and found out, that the **permission strings are actual property names**.

If you want to change `"Don't Ask"` text simply add the property with same name to your localization resource bundle (and use localization properly)

There is still a question how to get a list of all "hardcoded" strings to achieve complete app localization.

Comment: FYI this was covered in this article: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/switching-on-android-marshmallow-permission-prompts.html and in the developer guide here: https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html